# Replacing '\' with '\\'

Tags: python, python-2.7, replace, backslash

I'm trying to replace '\' with '\\', but its not working as i thought.

I tried using `f.replace('\','\\')`, but it is giving error like **unexpected character after line continuation character.**

```py
files = []
# r=root, d=directories, f = files
for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for file in f:
        if '.dcap' in file:
            files.append(os.path.join(r, file))

for f in files:
    print(f)
    f.replace( '\' , '\\')
    os.system("dcapgen.exe f")
```

Basically i want to run .exe file on all the .dcap files in the given directory(path). while printing f in files, its giving file path name like **C:\Users\folder\a.dcap**. but while giving `os.system("dcapgen.exe f")`, because f is representing C:\Users\folder\a.dcap and single backslash is not recognized by python, its throwing error like

***Tracing file: f
failed.
The file can still be processed, but the total frame count may show as zero and an error message may be generated for the final frame.
Cannot open file: "f" (No such file or directory)***

so, i want to replace single backslash with double one. And i tried using `os.system("dcapgen.exe C:\\Users\\folder\\a.dcap")` and its working fine.

Comment: try to use the other `/`for a folder path, instead of using `\`

Comment: replace( '\\' , '\\\\') replace (\\ = "\") with (\\ = "\") +( \\="\") = \\. You always have to double up \ as they escape the next character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`f` is a variable. To use a variable in a string yuu'll need [string Interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)

You could use `%-formatting`

```
files = []
# r=root, d=directories, f = files
for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for file in f:
        if '.dcap' in file:
            files.append(os.path.join(r, file))

for f in files:
    print(f)
    f.replace( '\' , '\\')
    os.system("dcapgen.exe %s" % f)
```

Comment: Was adding that in @Docteur

Comment: @MadhanVaradhodiyil, you need to remove this `f.replace( '\' , '\\')` as well. Anyways, Thanks buddy, its working.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to solve the problem differently. First of all there is the built-in package `glob`, which gives you the opportunity to use the asterisk as wildcard character to filter for the files of a certain type. Secondly you do not have to replace the file separators.

**CODE**

```py
import glob
import os

files = glob.glob("{}{}*.dcap".format(path, os.filesep)

for f in files:
    print(f)
    os.system("dcapgen.exe \"{}\"".format(f))
```

---

**EXPLANATION**

The backslash character is escaping everything. So when you write `'\', '\\'`, it actually resolves to this string `',` plus the invalid sequence `\\'`. This is the cause for the error regarding the line continuation.

If you want to use the value of a string variable in another string you have to use a formatted string. I would recommend to use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) instead of the modulo operation because it is more safe in terms of mishaps. In the error message it says that the file name "f" cannot be resolved by the operating system. This does not mean value of `f` but the literal string "f" as file name.